# FPDF Page wise style and size

Tags: fpdf

I want to generate PDF using FPDF library, but I am facing one issue that I can only provide fixed style and size for all pages. But my requirement is that I should provide dynamic style and size in FPDF object.

What can I try to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by style? Orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/)**

You can find [many examples](https://tcpdf.org/examples/) with more features than FPDF. You can use methods to publish some XHTML + CSS code, Javascript and Forms in a PDF format.

Some other features:

- custom page formats, custom margins and units of measure;
- automatic page header and footer management;
- PDF annotations, including links, text and file attachments;
- text rendering modes (fill, stroke and clipping);
- multiple columns mode;
- no-write page regions;
- text stretching and spacing (tracking/kerning);
- automatic page break, line break and text alignments including justification;
- automatic page numbering and page groups;
- move and delete pages;

Comment: Does it convert image to pdf ?

Comment: read documentations please. It has many features! for [image](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_009/)

Comment: but here object will only to be created once, you can't create object more then one time and style and size you can only pass once

Comment: What do you mean? You can do everything with this library! Did you see examples? What is your exact requirement?

Comment: I have also checked constructor, which also require single value, we are not able to pass array and you are talking about image size and style and i am asking pdf pages style and size.

Comment: You ask me about image So I talk about image. Did you check `WriteHTML` method. You can draw every page with a different width and height.

Comment: But i don't want html to pdf , I want image to pdf

Comment: Also in this html to pdf , dynamic style and size need to pass in object and it will also take static height and width that we have mentioned not in array different size and width

Comment: If possible please provide solution in FPDF, because all MPDF, TCPDF, etc working same ways